Do different "universes" (or vacua) in cosmological inflation (and similar models) have their own "celestial spheres"?
I was reading some papers* on celestial holography which aims to apply the holographic principle to an asymptotic flat spacetime, making a duality between a celestial sphere and a celestial conformal field theory (CCFT). I had a couple of questions on this:

Given an asymptotically flat spacetime, there is one celestial sphere. However, if we apply this to inflationary models where different "pocket universes" would have their own spacetime, would each one of them have their own celestial sphere? Or perhaps if there would be more than one possible vacua (as it happens in string theory landscape) described by different types of spacetime?

I did a question to Andrew Strominger, one of the researchers on this topic, namely:



"Since in your paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04208) you say that celestial amplitudes can be used to study UV complete theories, and therefore, to study possible consistent theories of quantum gravity, does it mean that we can use them to study every possible UV completion theory? All possible GUTs and all possible theories of quantum gravity? Could we use it to study every possible theory of everything like string theory, M-theory, loop quantum gravity, asymptotically safe quantum gravity...?".

His answer was basically a "yes". As a contributor in this page answered in a previous question I did on the topic, one could say that a theory is defined by prescribing all possible correlators. As such, given a quantum theory of gravity, you know all celestial amplitudes and, hence, the correlators of the dual theory. So, in this sense, the theory always can be represented in celestial holography
Then, all of this makes me wonder: In case the previous question is right, and there can be more than one celestial sphere in some sense, is it possible that different CCFTs corresponding to these different fundamental theories of quantum gravity could exist in different celestial spheres? Or something similar to this? Or is it forbidden?
*the papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12469
https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04208
https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.03932

I have a déjà-vu, did you post a similar question some weeks ago?

Your last question really doesn't make sense. There is one celestial sphere. What does it even mean to say that different theories live in different celestial spheres? I don't understand the comment you made on the same question you've asked 3 times previously either.

This question is similar to: Vacua in holography?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Prahar okay so I thought that an asymptotically flat spacetime would have its own celestial sphere, so that if we have different inflating zones in eternal inflation described by different asymptotically flat spaces then there would be different celestial spheres. If this is wrong or does not make sense then, may I change my original question: If there is only one celestial sphere, then, could different quantum theories of gravity correspond to different CCFTs in the same celestial sphere (so that different regions of the universe would be described by different theories of gravity)?

The thing is that I'm trying to make sense out of what Strominger said and what I've read in Freidel and Ciambelli works  (that all possible theories of quantum gravity are compatible with quasi-local holography and corner symmetry, which are very related to celestial holography). I thought that multiple celestial spheres could have different CCFTs corresponding to all these different quantum gravity theories. If this doesn't make sense, then, could different CCFTs corresponding to different quantum gravity theories exist in the same celestial sphere? Or that doesn't make sense either? @Prahar

Yes, the latter makes sense. Different CCFTs are dual to different bulk QG theories. Each such QG theory lives in its own asymptotically flat universe with its own celestial sphere. A specific bulk universe is described by a single QG theory which is dual to a single CCFT that lives on a single celestial sphere.

Okay, so if I understood it correctly, there could be different CCFTs coexisting in the same celestial sphere that would correspond to different QG theories in different asymptotically flat spacetimes (or "universes") in the bulk (with their own celestial spheres), correct? @Prahar

I simply don't understand what you mean by different "CCFTs co-existing". If celestial holography is correct, then one CCFT on a celestial sphere is dual to a single QG theory in AFS.
